# How to remove focus to react-modal component

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, tabindex, react-modal

For accessibility purposes, I need to remove focusability for react-modal. I'm using the accessibility testing tool ANDI and when run on my page, I get the alert: `Focusable element is not in keyboard tab order; should it be tabbable?`

I've tried making the element non-focusable using a variety of aria attributes (disabled, hidden, readonly, etc) as well as other methods and had no luck.

EDIT: to clarify, I'm trying to remove focus on the Modal component itself. Any suggestions to make the component non-focusable are much appreciated

```
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

type TProps = {
  isModalOpen: boolean;
  modalContent?: any;
  children?: any;
  toggleModal: () => void;
  render?: () => any;
  allowOverflow?: boolean;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
  maxHeight?: string;
  maxWidth?: string;
  className?: string;
};

export const CustomModal = (props:TProps) => {
  const [isModalOpen, toggleModal] = useState<boolean>(props.isModalOpen);

  const defaultStyle = {
    content: {
      top            : '50%',
      left           : '50%',
      right          : 'auto',
      bottom         : 'auto',
      marginRight    : '-40%',
      transform      : 'translate(calc(-37% - 0.5px), calc(-40% - 0.1px))',
      width          : props.width || 'fit-content',
      maxWidth       : props.maxWidth || '600px',
      height         : props.height || '97%',
      boxShadow      : '0px -1px 16px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
      padding        : '0px',
      inset          : '40.3% auto auto 50%',
      overflow       : `${props.allowOverflow ? 'visible' : 'auto'}`,
      maxHeight      : props.maxHeight || '97%'
    }
  };

  const handleExit = () => {
    toggleModal(false);
    props.toggleModal()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    toggleModal(props.isModalOpen);
  }, [props.isModalOpen])

  Modal.setAppElement(document.body)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Modal
      style={defaultStyle}
      isOpen={isModalOpen}
      onRequestClose={() => handleExit()}
      shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}>

        <div className={`content-container ${props.className ? props.className : ''}`}
             data-testid={`customModalContent`}>
          <div className='exit-button-container'>
            <i className='fas fa-times'
              data-testid={`customModalCloseButton`}
              onClick={() => handleExit()}/>
          </div>
          {(props.isModalOpen || isModalOpen) && props.modalContent && React.createElement(props.modalContent)}
          {(props.isModalOpen || isModalOpen) && props.render && props.render()}
          {props.children || <></>}
        </div>
        
    </Modal>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how we could possibly help here without any code. Please share what you got.

Comment: @Dominik Revised